# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 14633: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python-3.x

I am following this code bellow and have this issue, does anybody know what is wrong or how to fix it?

Issue:

> utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 14633: invalid
>   continuation byte

code:

```
    # Import DataReader
from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader

    # Import date
from datetime import date

    # Set start and end dates
start = date(2016, 1, 1)
end = date(2016, 12, 31)

    # Set the ticker
ticker = 'APPL'

    # Set the data source
data_source = 'google'

    # Import the stock prices
stock_prices = DataReader(ticker, data_source, start, end)

    # Display and inspect the result
print(stock_prices.head())
stock_prices.info()
```

Comment: what about the issue? any tip?